# 'Quake I'-style Specular Lighting?

Tags: 3d, game-engine, lighting

After a bit of casual reading, I found out that Quake 1 used pre-baked lightmaps for static geometry.

How (if it is there) can specular lighting calculations be done on this static geometry, since specular highlight changes intensity depending on the view position? It can't be baked into the lightmap texture, right?

Quake was released in 1996, before GLSL, so I'm assuming if there is specular lighting on static geometry it must be done on the CPU unless `GL_LIGHTING` was used. I assume this isn't the case as most Quake 1 maps have well over 8 lights ...

Comment: All GL-based Quake clients are *modern*, The original was a pure software renderer.

Comment: Offhand, it seems it was using a combination of lightmaps and traditional point-lights; the maps giving general ambient lighting + fuax-specularity, point lights giving dynamic lighting and true-spec. But don't quote me on that.